# Load web page contents in console application using c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, console-application, asp.net-webpages

I want to load contents of below web page in console application using c#.
http://justicecourts.maricopa.gov/findacase/casehistory.aspx

Using below code I am getting empty on the screen but it works perfectly if I load google.com web page.

By using WebClient and WebRequest I was getting error "Please enable javascript" and content was not loading so I used below code and javascipt error is not displaying now but web page content is not loading. I am struggling with this issue quite from long time, have seen lot of post regarding this and couldn't get this work.

Could anyone please help?

Thanks in Advance..

```
class Program
{
    private static bool completed = false;
    private static WebBrowser wb;
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        wb = new WebBrowser();
        wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted);
        wb.Navigate("http://justicecourts.maricopa.gov/findacase/casehistory.aspx");
        while (!completed)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        Console.Write("\n\nDone with it!\n\n");
        Console.ReadLine();


    }

    static void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(wb.Document.Body.InnerHtml);
        completed = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: AFAIK neither WebClient nor WebBrowser support Javascript.  You will get the same error using the WebBrowser control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding more wait.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        wb = new WebBrowser();
        wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted);
        wb.Navigate("http://justicecourts.maricopa.gov/findacase/casehistory.aspx");
        while (!completed)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
       //wait even more
       for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        Console.Write("\n\nDone with it!\n\n");
        Console.ReadLine();


    }
```

otherwise you can use [EO](http://www.essentialobjects.com/products/webbrowser/default.aspx) Browser it is paid. but in your case trail will work cause it is not GUI application.as it shows trail message in GUI.

in EO you can say..

```
EOContorol.WebView.LoadUrlAndWait(URL);
```

Comment: Awesome @sm.abdullah, page is loading successfully. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

If you literally just want to dump the contents of that URL out to the console, try this:

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
   Console.WriteLine(client.DownloadString(url));
}
```

Comment: perfect!! it s also exec javascript!

Comment: HttpClient wont load content that is generated from javascript. Instead you can use WebView that will run js. I ran both, HttpClient result had length of 235507 and WebView result lenght of 464476.

Answer (score -1):

Try using [PhantomJs](http://www.nrecosite.com/phantomjs_wrapper_net.aspx)
basicaly like running a webbrowser without a window. (headless)